# How to improve simulated annealing for playfair in python - how to make sure that the score goes up?

Tags: python, simulated-annealing

It seems that the child always sets itself to equal parent even though the conditions are not satisfied. Any help? Is this because of the layering?

```
def crack(ct):
    temp = 10 + 0.087 * (len(ct)-84)
    fit = ns.ngram_score('english_quadgrams.txt')
    while 1 == 1:
        parent = randkey()
        counter = 0
        while counter < 50000:
            ps = fit.score((de(ct,parent)).upper())
            number = rd.randint(1,25)
            if number == 1:
               child = nw(parent)
            else:
                if number == 2:
                    child = td(parent)
                else:
                    if number == 3:
                        child = lr(parent)
                    else:
                        if number == 4:
                            child = randr(parent)
                        else:
                            if number == 5:
                                child = randc(parent)
                            else:
                                child = rand2(parent)
            print(de(ct,child))
            cs = fit.score((de(ct,child)).upper())
            diff = ps-cs
            print(ps,cs, diff)
            prob = 1/(math.exp(diff/temp))
            print(prob)
            random = rd.uniform(0,1)
            print(random)
            if diff < 0:
                parent = child
            elif prob < random:
                counter = counter + 1
            else:
                parent = child
```

The score is computed based on the [quadgram rating](http://practicalcryptography.com/cryptanalysis/text-characterisation/quadgrams/) texts and library based on here. Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: You might want to flatten things up a bit. I found it fun to flatten that long if else chain with `child = (None, nw, td, lr, randr, randc, rand2)[max(number, 6)](parent)`... though just using `elif` would work too. Similarly, use `elif` for the `if diff > 0` stuff.

Comment: It doesn't look like your `temp` ever changes. Isn't the point of simulated annealing to cool down over time?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Thank you! I don't understand how the flattening works. The algorithm always returns "tuple out of range" for a playfair ciphertext under the flattening...I'm still finding a way to relate the temperature to the algorithm. In all cases, the scoring doesn't seem to be going down.

Comment: Sorry, that `max` should have been a `min`. But I think using `elif` is also clearer.

Comment: Are you trying to reduce or increase the score? Your signs might be wrong. `diff = cs - ps`. If that doesn't fix it, make sure your `prob` also makes sense.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Thanks. It seems like the child is becoming the parent automatically even when I remove the part under prob... How could this happen?

Comment: Did you try decaying the temperature value each loop cycle?